# CI template - element is displayed in wrong place

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problems displaying views with a template. 
My template looks like this:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('includes/header');

if($this->session->userdata('is_loggedin')!=1) //check if logged in 
{
    $this->load->view('includes/not_loggedin');  //includes this when not logged in
} 
else //includes all this when is logged in
{
     if(isset($content)) //check if content variable isnt empty
     {
         $this->load->view($content); //THIS IS MY CONTENT WHIC IS DISPLAYED IN WRONG POS
     }
    $this->load->view('includes/is_loggedin'); //
}

$this->load->view('includes/footer');
?>
```

By wrong position, I mean that my form is being displayed in the top lefthand corner outside of the HTML structure. Here is a copy from inspect element window. Notice where the div is located; the head tags are empty; and, the head information is in body.

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head> //head tags are empty
<body>
<div id="settings">...</div>  //this is my loaded div 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sludinājumu lapa</title> //head info outside tags
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="wrapper">....</div>  //i need settings div inside wrapper div 
</body>
</html>
```

Without loading that view, the HTML structure is fine. Also there is no problems with loading is_loggedin and not_logged into the views.

My header contains :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sludinājumu lapa</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
```

And the footer contains:

```
<foter>
<p>developed by kriss</p>
</foter>
</div> //End of "wrapper" div
</body>
</html>
```

From the controller I am passing the data like this:

```
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('vchangeinfo');
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Any ideas why everything is so messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

[Codeigniter views](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Load it in advance (like you're doing) and pass to the other view

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
// the "TRUE" argument tells it to return the content, rather than display it immediately
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('vchangeinfo', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view ('template', $data);

// View

if(isset($content)) //check if content variable isnt empty
{
    $this->load->view($content);
    // OR don't know wich one works.
    // echo $content;
}
```

Load a view "from within" a view:

```
<?php
// Controller
$this->load->view('template');

<?php
// Views :  /application/views/template.php
$this->view('vchangeinfo');
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. echo $content is working , because if i load view $this->load->view($content); all views UNDER this line of code isn't working, but all views above are loading fine.....wonder why...

Comment: Maybe because you are using two times the $this->load->view($content);
One time in the controller et an other time in the view. (not sure about it but can maybe explain)